# Code was working and now I get Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, offset

I'm getting this error "Runtime error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error"

My code was working with no issues, but I had to delete the sheet I was writing the results to ("RawData"), I created a new sheet with the same name and now I'm getting this error. I tried creating a new sheet with a different name and changing all the references in the macro but it is still giving me this error. Tried creating a new file and copy everything to it, and still the same. Have other files with the same code working so I don't know what to do now. Tried adding .Activate and nothing.

Help

```
Sheets("CE").Select
    Range("d3:d8").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("RawData").Select
Range("b1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer? I know this sounds obtuse but sometimes a VBA environment gets corrupted.

Comment: Can't test as on my phone but i think the offset will be looking off the bottom of the sheet if column B is empty. If you're ignoring errors in the code it may just stop.

Comment: Rebooting is a simple step that is too-often overlooked.  A reboot can fix everything from phones to toys to relationships to TV sitcoms

Comment: As @DarrenBartrup-Cook said, the `End(xlDown)` in a completely blank column (or where cell B1 was the only value in the column) is going to put you at the bottom row of the sheet and then you are trying to select the row one below that - which will give the error you are getting.

Comment: Tried resetting the computer and it's still the same. I don't know how to troubleshoot since it was working before, all I did was delete the sheet create a new one and name it the same, so I don't know how it got damaged

Comment: @YowE3K Thank, you I had only 1 row of information so it wasn't totally empty, I added a second row and it worked again. Thank you for the explanation as it helps me try something else. Is there a better function to use to write on the next available row than "End(x1Down)" ?

Comment: Typo in your last comment - `xlDown`, not `x1Down` (we get that issue a lot).  Yes, use `xlUp`.  See @Jeeped's comment to ashleedawg's answer (although `"b&ROWS.COUNT"` should actually be `"b" & Rows.Count`)

Comment: `End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention a key piece of information that leads to a simple solution.  *Which error* you're getting is important -- but of equal or more importance is **where** the error is occurring, as in, which line is the code breaking on.

```
End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

*"Take me to the end of the universe.  And then one step farther."*  :-)

---

[image: xlDirection]
<sup>it's a lonely club to be a member of</sup>

Comment: This solution seems very likely as the OP *'created a new sheet'*.

Comment: so?  New sheets have ends too!

Comment: uh... I was agreeing with you. A new worksheet likely doesn't have any information. btw, maybe you could suggest `Range("b&ROWS.COUNT").End(xlUP).Offset(1, 0).Select`

Comment: P.S. I thought of the Buzz Lightyear quote "To infinity, and beyond!"

Comment: The OP's deduction method is flawed.  The new sheet was not the only thing that changed.  (although my next request would have been for a screen shot showing the actual worksheet name, as small typos are easily overlooked.)

Comment: NO Buzz, I keep telling you, you can **not** go beyond infinity.

Comment: That was the issue, I knew it couldn't be empty so I added 1 row of information, came to find out you need 2 rows for it to work. Is it better to use End(x1Up) than End(x1Down)? what is the difference?

Comment: I'd imagine one goes up and one goes down.  :-)

Comment: yup, I was right.  Photo added to answer.  Now we know.

Comment: @CamiloQuevedo - x**L**up starts from the bottom row and looks up then moves one cell down. x**L**down starts at the top and looks down.

Comment: @Jeeped you have a typo. Upvoted answer literally just for the joke.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to look for the first blank row from the bottom:

```
Sub Test()
    Sheets("CE").Range("d3:d8").Copy
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```